# cannot find element after being redirected to a webpage - python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

this is not the exact code but basically the bug is the same. I use python selenium to go on a website. There are two buttons. The first one redirects me to one page. The second button is on that page that is has redirectd me to. For some reason, it says that the button on the second page cannot be found.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\angel\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")

#techwithtim cause why not 

driver.get('https://www.techwithtim.net')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

#first button
buttonPath = r"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/aside[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a"
try:
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, buttonPath)
    button.click()
except:
    print("bad")

#second button on newly redirected webpage
secondPath = r"/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[1]/a"

secondButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, secondPath)
secondButton.click()
```

I redid my code into the smallest form above and still, it doesn't work for me. I made a try except block on the second button and it printed the page source which prints the html for the first webpage, not the redirected one. How can I fix this?

Sorry if this is an easy question since I am still very new to programming, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#Define web driver as a Chrome driver and navigate. I am in Linux, in Windows you can define your browser in the same way you were doing it.
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://www.techwithtim.net'
driver.get(url)

# First button
buttonPath = "//li[@id='menu-item-402']/a"
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, buttonPath)))
button.click()


# Second button on newly redirected webpage
secondPath = "//li[@id='menu-item-156']/a"
secondButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, secondPath)))
secondButton.click()
```

2 Advices:

1. Try to locate your elements with simple locators, if you see my xpath it is really simple.
2. Always, when you have to interact with an element, try to wait for it till it is ready.